# How to create a basic gallery grid using an unordered list

Tags: html, css, user-interface, flexbox, grid

Using flex, I'm trying to create a gallery grid using an unordered list item.

It requires the first image to be 50%, then the other 4 images alongside it in a grid.

I have attached a js fiddle and an image of what I'm after, as I can't figure out where I'm going wrong.

http://jsfiddle.net/qj7u5tv6/

[image: grid gallery using flex]

```
li:first-child{
  width: 50%;
} 

li:not(:first-child)  {
  width: 25%;
  flex-direction: row;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  
}

Thanks
```

Comment: If you are using flex, it won't be possible with your actual markup. You would need a container for the 4 images on the right. It would be trivial using grid though.

Comment: Not opposed to using grid if thats do-able?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `grid` it's pretty trivial.

Your layout is basically a two rows and 3 columns layout.
Both rows take `50%` of the height or in fraction `1fr`, while for first column takes `50%` of the width and the others `25%` or in fraction: `2fr`, `1fr` and `1fr`.

The first image spans across the two rows.

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 2fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
}

li:first-child {
  grid-row: span 2;
}
```

If you want a gap, you can add it to the grid:

```css
  gap: 1rem;
```

To have the pictures fill their cells:

```css
img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

**Snippet:**

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 2fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
  gap: 1rem;
}

li:first-child {
  grid-row: span 2;
}

img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400" />
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400" />
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400" />
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400" />
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400" />
  </li>
</ul>
```